# OpenCV 3.0.0 with cuda : too many resources requested for launch

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, opencv3.0

I have compiled OpenCV 3.0.0 from latest source (2014.09.22)

I'm trying to use `opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/samples/surf_matcher.cpp` without success.

My code:

```
int surf() {
   cv::cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo( cv::cuda::getDevice( ) );

   cv::cuda::SURF_CUDA surf;
   std::cerr << "- 1 -" << std::endl;
   cv::cuda::GpuMat img1, keypoints1GPU, descriptors1GPU;
   std::cerr << "- 2 -" << std::endl;
   cv::Mat im1( imread( "shapes.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE ));
   std::cerr << "- 3 - load(): " << ( im1.data ? "OK" : "failed" ) << std::endl;
   img1.upload( im1 );
   std::cerr << "- 4 -" << std::endl;
   surf( img1, cv::cuda::GpuMat(), keypoints1GPU, descriptors1GPU );
   std::cerr << "- 5 -" << std::endl;
```

The console:

```
Device 0:  "GeForce 8600 GT"  256Mb, sm_11 (not Fermi), 32 cores,
   Driver/Runtime ver.6.50/6.50
- 1 -
- 2 -
- 3 - load(): OK
- 4 -
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (too many resources requested for launch) in
   cv::cuda::device::surf::compute_descriptors_gpu,
   file D:/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/cuda/surf.cu, line 947
D:/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/cuda/surf.cu:947: error: (-217)
   too many resources requested for launch in function
   cv::cuda::device::surf::compute_descriptors_gpu
```

FYI here is the code of `surf.cu`:

```
void compute_descriptors_gpu(
   PtrStepSz<float4>  descriptors,
   const float *      featureX,
   const float *      featureY,
   const float *      featureSize,
   const float *      featureDir,
   int                nFeatures )
{
   if( descriptors.cols == 64 ) {
      ...            
   }
   else {
      compute_descriptors_128<<<nFeatures, dim3(32, 16)>>>(
         descriptors, featureX, featureY, featureSize, featureDir );
      cudaSafeCall( cudaGetLastError()); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< line 947
```

OS: WINDOWS 7 64 bit

VisualStudio Express 2013, target Win32, debug mode

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking too many features for your GPU, try lowering the value if you can

Comment: This GPU card is old, yes, it's true. Lack of processors or RAM?

Comment: I would take a look at 'src/cuda/surf.cu:947' and see what launch is failing and check for the resources asked to my GPU